# Exposing WSDL on BasicHttpRelayBinding over Azure

Tags: azure, wsdl, azureservicebus, basichttprelaybinding

I have an svc that is auto-started using AppFabric. What I want to do is [expose the wsdl for my service over the bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706721.aspx). Internally the service and the wsdl work fine of course, I can also consume the service over the bus with no issue. The only thing I can't configure properly is viewing the wsdl over the relay.

The `ServiceHostFactory` creates default endpoints and also adds an Azure Endpoint along with a mex endpoint in hopes to expose the wsdl over the relay. When I try to view the wsdl from the service bus url, I get the mismatch fault, probably due to ACS authentication failing?

```
...cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree
```

Do I need to set the mex endpoint up as anonymous authentication so I can go to a browser and view the wsdl? Just not sure what else to try... Any help would be appreciated!

Example url:

http://myservicebusexample.servicebus.windows.net/MyService/AService.svc?wsdl

or

http://myservicebusexample.servicebus.windows.net/MyService/AService.svc/mex

```
<serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
   </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

So here is my `ServiceHostFactory`

```cs
// Create host with default endpoints
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
host.AddDefaultEndpoints();

// Create Relay Endpoint for Azure
ServiceEndpoint relayEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyContract), new BasicHttpRelayBinding("MyAzureBindingConfiguration"), relayAddress);

// Apply ACS Credentials for the relay endpoint
relayEndpoint.ApplyEndpointBehaviorConfig("MyAzureACSCredentials");

// Create mex Endpoint to expose wsdl over the relay
ServiceEndpoint mexEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                       new BasicHttpRelayBinding("MyAzureBindingConfiguration"),
                       "mex");

// Apply ACS Credentials for the mex endpoint
mexEndpoint.ApplyEndpointBehaviorConfig("MyAzureACSCredentials");
```

Comment: Gabe - did you every figure this out?  I have a netTcpRelay binding and I'm trying to expose metadata with basicHttpRelay and netTcpRelay and haven't had success with either.

Comment: No, never found a way around it. I ended up having to make a service agent for the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the serviceBehavior which enables the metadata behavior:

```
 <behavior>
    <serviceMetadata />
 </behavior>
```

Comment: I should have noted in the question that I do have that. Thanks for the trying though, it's appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to change ?wsdl to /mex - like this: http://....windows.net/MyService/AService.svc/mex

Comment: Tried that too with the same result