# Azure Relay for Soap WebServices

Tags: c#, azure, web-services, soap, azure-servicebusrelay

I've recently discovered Azure Relay and it seems very powerful.  I have a basic project using it now to expose a WCF Windows Service.  I've read in the documentation about how it can be used to expose RESTful services, but I'm having trouble understanding if it can be used to expose a SOAP web service.  I can't seem to find any examples of that and the closest I can is [this post about exposing the WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923026/exposing-wsdl-on-basichttprelaybinding-over-azure).  I have an extremely simple SOAP web service with a single method that takes in 5 strings as arguments.  I know WCF Services can be hosted in IIS but my client's requirement is that no firewall ports are opened so here's my actual question:

Is there a way to use a Relay to expose an internal IIS WebService publicly?  Is there another method I might have overlooked to get around opening a port in the firewall?

I would be very open to exposing the service I have or rewriting it completely since it's so simple, I'm just not sure what my options are.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to re-implement the service as RESTful service or as a **Web API** and then use [Azure's API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/) to expose it to the outer world.

Hope it helps!